# Devise Omniauth + Facebook Error Not found. Authentication passthru

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

im a big problem i follow the instructions in :

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

To implement Devise Facebook Omniauth in my app, i put this in

**devise.rb (i use MAC OSX)**

```
  require "omniauth-facebook"
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if Rails.env.development?
  config.omniauth :facebook, "501422263262172", "75b6641e4af169e385749060df0963a4"
```

this in model

**user.rb**

```
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(:name => auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                         :provider => auth.provider,
                         :uid => auth.uid,
                         :email => auth.info.email,
                         :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      )
    end
    user
  end


  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
         :validatable,:omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

and this in

**users/ominiauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController


  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end


end
```

and this in

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

But when i click in link to login whit Facebook appear this:

**Not found. Authentication passthru.**

Please help me i dont know what is wrong i remake the process and appear same error, thanks much if someone doubt about the code I am here to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this upgrading from **Rails 3.2** and Ruby **1.9.3** to **Rails 4.0** and Ruby **2.0.0**.